# java.sql.SQLException:near"İşlem":Syntax error

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans

I started to working on SQLite database for my table. And I'm getting this error when I'm trying to save informations to database with text lanes. I'm working with NetBeans.

```
private void Cmd_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
   try{
      String sql = "Insert into KYaziciProg (Yapılan İşlem ,Müşteri Adı ,Ürünün Cinsi ,Ürünün Miktarı ,Ürünün Fiyatı ,Ürünün Tutarı ,İşlem Tarihi ,Ödeme Vadesi ,Yapılan Ödeme ,Kalan Bakiye) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

      pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
      pst.setString(3, jTextField1.getText());
      pst.setString(4, jTextField3.getText());
      pst.setString(5, jTextField4.getText());
      pst.setString(6, jTextField5.getText());
      pst.setString(7, jTextField6.getText());
      pst.setString(8, jTextField7.getText());
      pst.setString(9, jTextField8.getText());
      pst.setString(10, jTextField9.getText());
      pst.setString(11, jTextField10.getText());

      pst.execute();

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Kaydedildi!");

   }   
   catch(Exception e)
   {     
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);   
   }  
   Update_table();
}
```

This is the codes where I'm trying to get this ones. I started from 2 in setString . Because I don't know but in SQLite I saw 1 more column which I didn't create before. See the image below
[image: colmuns]

EDIT:

Same error on when clicked button. I saw these errors on the Run Panel;
run:

```
java.sql.SQLException: near "İşlem": syntax error
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:37)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:231)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:213)
    at populatethingy.Cmd_saveActionPerformed(populatethingy.java:253)
    at populatethingy.access$300(populatethingy.java:13)
    at populatethingy$4.actionPerformed(populatethingy.java:210)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6289)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6054)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:644)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:617)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:615)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns have spaces in them, you need to quote them, so:

```
Insert into KYaziciProg ("Yapılan İşlem" ,"Müşteri Adı" , ...
```

Comment: Waow dude you're amazing :D Java Devil too but , i dont know. Thanks a lot. I changed it like that and it works now ! ^^  "Yapılan İşlem","Müşteri Adı","Ürünün Cinsi","Ürünün Miktarı","Ürünün Fiyatı","Ürünün Tutarı","İşlem Tarihi","Ödeme Vadesi","Yapılan Ödeme","Kalan Bakiye"

Comment: Completely missed that, was to busy trying to explain incorrect parameter indices, would have been the next problem he would have encountered though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from 1. The Column `ROWID` is autogenerated by Sqlite.

But that wouldn't matter anyway as if you look at your insert statement, you do not specify that column so you are not inserting into into that column.

The parameter index corresponds to the `?` characters in your insert statement so you are getting that error because the way your code is now you would be trying to execute the statement (Note that `"Value from jTextFeildX` is just my puesdo string for what ever the value is.

> Insert into KYaziciProg (Yapılan İşlem ,Müşteri Adı ,Ürünün Cinsi ,Ürünün Miktarı ,Ürünün Fiyatı ,Ürünün Tutarı ,İşlem Tarihi ,Ödeme Vadesi ,Yapılan Ödeme ,Kalan Bakiye) values (**?**,value from jTextFeildX,value from jTextFeildX,value from jTextFeildX,value from jTextFeildX,value from jTextFeildX,value from jTextFeildX,value from jTextFeildX,value from jTextFeildX,value from jTextFeildX)";

Notice that there is a `?` still in the query.. meaning invalid SQL

You want your code to be

```
  pst.setString(1, jTextField2.getText());
  pst.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());
  pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
  pst.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());
  pst.setString(5, jTextField5.getText());
  pst.setString(6, jTextField6.getText());
  pst.setString(7, jTextField7.getText());
  pst.setString(8, jTextField8.getText());
  pst.setString(9, jTextField9.getText());
  pst.setString(10, jTextField10.getText());
```

**EDIT**
Add this code and the go to your netbeans ouput console and post to your question the resulting lines.

```
catch(Exception e)
{  
  e.printStackTrace();    // Add this line 
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Is that form or from ? So i need to do that for every "?" ? ^^

Comment: For every `?` you have in your query/insert there should be a corresponding `pst.set`, always starting with index 1 for the first `?`

Comment: (?,"Value from jTextField2",?"Value from jTextField1",?"Value from jTextField3",?"Value from jTextField4",?"Value from jTextField5",?"Value from jTextField6",?"Value from jTextField7",?"Value from jTextField8",?"Value from jTextField9",?"Value from jTextField10") Sorry dude i understood just like that. Is it wrong ? If i made you sick about that i'm really sorry because i'm fighting with this error like for a 2-3 hours

Comment: It's giving error too which i wrote here. So how frequently should i use "Value from jTextField2" . Dude really really i did not understand anything about this thing. And i'm so appreciated to you about helping me ..

Comment: Thanks i changed the number of the strings. And putted back ? 's . And error still resuming.. I think i need to understood "Value from JTextField2" thing..

Comment: There is nothing to understand about that, it was just a placeholder string I was using to describe what ever the code `jTextField2.getText()` was returning. Update your question with the full stack trace error you get (add `e.printStackTrace()` to your catch block)

Comment: I updated it with your advices/codes which you gave me in the comments.

Comment: Ok one last time before I give up `value from jTextField7` **IS NOT CODE**, CHANGE THEM TO `?`

Comment: String sql = "Insert into KYaziciProg (Yapılan İşlem ,Müşteri Adı ,Ürünün Cinsi ,Ürünün Miktarı ,Ürünün Fiyatı ,Ürünün Tutarı ,İşlem Tarihi ,Ödeme Vadesi ,Yapılan Ödeme ,Kalan Bakiye) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";  Dude please you're java devil :( I did it it like that. It's keeping error. Are you sure error's source coming from here ?

Comment: No I'm not, that's why I asked to post the full error you are getting, but then you posted all your code... not what I asked for

Comment: OMG :S I'm so sorry .Here is the error.. java.sql.SQLException:near"İşlem":Syntax error

Comment: I'm getting this error in table while running. When i clicked "Kaydet" button. It giving me this error...

Comment: See me edit, Once you have done that we will know more about what is causing your problem.

Comment: Same problem resuming. I added your code with same position like yours. And i see this this errors on "Run Panel" I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for everything dude. Problem fixed ^^ I just changed it like Mark's advice.